# Can I use 'this' in Angular 6 unit tests?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I recently upgraded from Angular 5 to Angular 6 and started using the cli. Before I was just using webpack with jasmine and karma to run my unit tests. The way I normally write my unit tests is like this:

```js
describe('ComponentToTest', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    this.injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      { provide: DALService, useClass: MockDal },
      RealService
    ]);

    this.datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
    this.component2 = this.injector.get(Component2);
    this.dal = this.injector.get(DALService);
    this.realService = this.injector.get(RealService);

    this.componentToTest = new ComponentToTest(
      this.datePipe,
      this.component2,
      this.dal,
      this.realService);

    // Test Data
    this.testData = [1, 2, 3];
  });

  describe('testFunctionOne', () => {
    it('should return true', () => {
      expect(this.componentToTest.testFunctionOne()).toEqual(true);
    });
  });
});
```

But with the cli project when I run "ng test" all the tests fail saying 'this' is undefined. E.g. One of the actual errors is:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'injector' of undefined
```

Can I not use 'this' in my tests anymore? Does everything have to be a variable declared inside the main describe?

Comment: A resource you may find valuable: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: That's great for overall reference, but I find my format much cleaner. I would prefer to keep using this if it's a simple change in my config somewhere.

Comment: inside of the `beforeEach` closure, what is `this` supposed to be?

Comment: I saw that format in an article about testing with Angular and found it much cleaner than declaring a bunch of variables at the top of describe. I assumed it was a feature of jasmine or karma, that it would create a 'this' scope for each test file.